# Google Analytics Measurement Protocol and Enhanced e-commerce not capturing revenue

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, revenue

I'm trying to use the measurement protocol to record an offline purchase on our backend system. The problem is, after I send the Measurement Protocol request, the goal conversion is captured correctly in GA's reports, but the revenue earned from the purchase is always displayed as 0.00 in the reports, even though I am sending a value of 500.00 in the revenue parameter.

Here is the request I am sending to the measurement protocol:

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?
v=1
&tid=UA-XXXXXXXXXX
&cid=XXXXXXX.XXXXXX
&uid=123
&t=pageview
&dh=http%253A%252F%252Fmydomain.com
&dp=order%2Fthank_you
&dt=thank+you
&ti=127210
&ta=offline+conversion
&tr=500.00
&pa=purchase
&pr1id=1864
&pr1nm=Abc+Program
&pr1ca=Software
&pr1pr=500.00
&cu=CNY
&sc=end
&aip=1
```

The next day, when I check GA's Conversions reports, it always displays the revenue earned as 0.00, even though I've specified the price to be 500.00 in the request.  I've already tried the following tasks to resolve the problem, but to no avail:

1. Double-check that Enhanced E-commerce is enabled in GA (it is).
2. Change &t=pageview to &t=transaction, but this modification results in neither the goal nor the revenue to be captured in GA.
3. Sent the request to /debug/collect to validate the hit (it is valid). Below is the response:

   ```
    "hitParsingResult": [ {
       "valid": true,
       "parserMessage": [ {
         "messageType": "INFO",
         "description": "IP Address from this hit was anonymized to 106.111.63.0.",
         "messageCode": "VALUE_MODIFIED"
       } ],
       "hit": "/debug/collect?v=1\u0026tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-X\u0026cid=XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXX\u0026uid=123\u0026t=pageview\u0026dh=http%253A%252F%252Fmydomain.com\u0026ti=127210\u0026ta=offline%20conversion\u0026tr=500.00\u0026pa=purchase\u0026pr1id=1864\u0026pr1nm=Abc%20Program\u0026pr1ca=Software\u0026pr1pr=500.00\u0026cu=CNY\u0026sc=end\u0026aip=1"
     } ],
     "parserMessage": [ {
       "messageType": "INFO",
       "description": "Found 1 hit in the request."
     } ]
   ```

Here is the screenshot of the above purchase in GA's conversion reports:

[image]

As shown above, the revenue from the purchase is 0.00, even though the revenue I sent to GA is 500.00.

Any idea why Google is not tracking the revenue?